# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript not calling Properly in Looping statement

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In asp.net C#, I'm tried to call my JavaScript from ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript using looping statement. But the JavaScript method calling only one time.

How can I call the JavaScript method in looping statement?

**C#-Code:**

```
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Print", "Print(" + i + ");", true);
}
```

**JavaScript-Code:**

```
function Print(i)
{
   console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

In the looping statement we need to add the separate key names.

**ASP.Net-Code**

```
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++)
{
   string keyName = "Print" + i;
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), keyName, "Print(" + i + ");", true);
}
```